# Set a unique validation error notice in Woocommerce checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, validation, woocommerce, checkout

Woocommerce checkout page shows individual error if the required fields are empty. Normally, if all fields are empty, all errors for those empty fields will be shown: 
- First name is a required field 
- Last name is a required field 
- Street address is a required field 
- Town / City is a required field 
*and so on…*

Is it possible to show only one error if all the required fields are empty? Like “ERROR: All fields are empty. Please fill in all required fields to place order.” How to achieve this?

Checkout page

[image: Checkout page]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To set a unique validation error notice in Woocommerce checkout page you will use the following: *(code is mainly from your last question and useful to the community. Just changed to the official function arguments code)*

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'checkout_validation_unique_error', 9999, 2 );
function checkout_validation_unique_error( $data, $errors ){
    // Check for any validation errors
    if( ! empty( $errors->get_error_codes() ) ) {

        // Remove all validation errors
        foreach( $errors->get_error_codes() as $code ) {
            $errors->remove( $code );
        }

        // Add a unique custom one
        $errors->add( 'validation', 'Please fill in all required fields to place order.' );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

**Related:** [Set a unique validation error notice in Woocommerce My Account Addresses and Account Details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53279751/set-a-unique-validation-error-notice-in-woocommerce-my-account-addresses-and-acc/53284620#53284620)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to disable the current error checking and write custom javascript for the checkout page that would put all the errors in a single message.

There's no native WooCommerce functionality that would accomplish this.

To remove validation, go to your checkout.php template and remove the `required` attribute from the html fields.

Checkout [this link](https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-add-html-javascript-checkout-page/) on how to add HTML and javascript to the checkout page.

Comment: thanks for this Difster. but my problem now is how to disable the current error checking for this fields.

Answer (score 0):

hHi, you can remove validation from checkout fields and add yours:

Here is the hook:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields' , 'filter_default_address_fields', 20, 1 );
```

for more, you can go to

> [therichpost](https://therichpost.com/category/woocommerce-hooks)

Comment: thankyou for this hook Ajay. but i dont think i can remove the validation for the checkout fields that easily for the fact that its validation is in woocommerce includes folder. but i'll try this hook. i'll let you know if it  works.

Comment: sure @natnat, if you want more help then you can reach me...therichpost

Comment: HI @natnat, can you show me your code or you can contact me for solution.

Answer (score -1):

Its normally show when you press the checkout button. but if you watch it when page load. then maybe it's come by woocommerce bugs. you should update woocommerce plugin. I hope this error would be gone when you will update the plugin.

But after that, if you are facing the same issue contact me. I will look at it.

thank you

Comment: actually this is not an error. this is how woocommerce reacts when a specific field is empty. i just want to override all the error that pops when all fields are empty.

Comment: then you can modify it using this filter add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields' , 'filter_default_address_fields', 20, 1 );