# Translate checkout fields validation error notices in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, validation, woocommerce, checkout

How to translate Woocommerce Checkout page validation error messages? I have tried to used

```
function ship_to_different_address_translation( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
    switch ( $translated_text ) {

        case 'Billing First name is a required field.' :
            if ( get_locale() == 'en_GB' ) {
                $translated_text = __( 'Please fill in all the required fields!', 'woocommerce' );
            }
            break;
    }

    return $translated_text;
}

add_filter('gettext', 'ship_to_different_address_translation', 20, 3);
```

This code works for all the strings (except checkout validation error messages). Is it possible to replace all the error messages with 'Please fill in all the required fields!'?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1) Customizing default validation error notices** for Woocommerce checkout fields:

You can use `woocommerce_checkout_required_field_notice` dedicated filter hook, to customize each notice, changing the text below:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_required_field_notice', 'custom_checkout_required_fields_error_notice', 10, 2 );
function custom_checkout_required_fields_error_notice( $error_notice, $field_label ) {
    $error_notice = sprintf( __( '%s is a required field.', 'woocommerce' ), '<strong>' . esc_html( $field_label ) . '</strong>' );

    return $error_notice; 
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.

**2) Replace all validation errors notice with a one unique custom error notice** for Woocommerce checkout fields:

See: [Set a unique validation error notice in Woocommerce checkout page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52987684/set-a-unique-validation-error-notice-in-woocommerce-checkout-page/53285338#53285338)